# How to include dependencies in a UWP package?

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge

I am developing an wpf app that uses Kinect sensor. We are converting it to UWP with the Desktop Bridge.

It runs fine if the Kinect Runtime is installed in the PC, but it crash if it is not installed. 
How can I include the [Kinect for Windows Runtime 2.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44559) installer in the app package. So when someone installs the app it automatically installs the runtime?

I also need to include the VC ++ 2013..

I can't find any doc about this online.

Comment: If you are using Kinect SDK, then it should automatically bundle in your project.

Comment: @Dishant Yes, I'm using Kinect SDK and works fine in my computer. But if you install the app on another computer it can't run without installing first the Kinect Runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.
The VC ++ 2013 problem was resolved following [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2016/10/20/desktop-bridge-how-to-handle-c-and-c-dependencies-with-the-desktop-app-converter/) mentioned by [Bogdan Mitrache](https://stackoverflow.com/users/882875/bogdan-mitrache)

The kinect runtime problem was caused by the Microsof.Kinect.dll I had in the project. It was the x64 version but the project was x86. If the Kinect Runtime is installed both dll versions (x86 and x64) are installed and it works. If not only the dll of the project is available. Replacing the dll of the project by a x86 version fixed the problem.

Also if you are interested this is the article I followed to include other dependencies needed [Chaining multiple installers with the Desktop App Converter](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2017/09/11/chaining-multiple-installers-with-the-desktop-app-converter/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually edit your **AppxManifest.xml** file and include there the list of dependencies. The following [article from Microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2016/10/20/desktop-bridge-how-to-handle-c-and-c-dependencies-with-the-desktop-app-converter/) has some examples.

Also, on the [same blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/tag/desktop-bridge/) you can find more useful examples related to the migration and configuration of Desktop Bridge apps, just filter them out by clicking on the "desktop bridge" tag.

Comment: Yes, I've seen and read that article but I think it doesn't talk about my problem. I don't have the warnings it says... I just need to include the other installers... But maybe it is not posible.